# What does it mean by, "No voltage is applied"?

Tags: circuit-analysis, network

I've a very basic query.
If a question says, "no voltage is applied to the circuit" does it mean the battery is replaced by short-circuit (since, no voltage => 0V) or by an open-circuit (literally, no battery is connected across the terminals of the circuit)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means you could replace the voltage sources with an open circuit. The battery could be taken out of the circuit and replaced with an open circuit.

In the physical world this would be the equivalent to disconnecting the wire from one of the battery terminals.